# Allow additional user(s) to access a Google Cloud Compute Engine Instance through Google Remote Desktop

Tags: google-cloud-platform, remote-desktop

I have created a Google Cloud Compute Engine instance, which I access through Google Chrome Remote Desktop (https://remotedesktop.google.com/access).  I would like to allow additional users to access this in the same way (that is, through Remote Desktop, terminal-based access is not suitable for my task).

I have started out by creating an additional gmail account to test this process on, and have granted it the role of 'Viewer' in IAM.  However, when this new user goes to the Remote Desktop URL, the instance is not listed there.  I tried granting this new user the role of 'Owner', and then, even though the new user had access to the Google Cloud dashboard for my project, it did not have the instance displayed on the Remote Desktop site.

Is there something else I need to do to allow this new user to have Remote Desktop access to the instance?

EDIT: As a comment asked for more details, I will try to add them.  I started out with 1 google account.  As this user, I was able to create the Compute Engine instance and connect to it through Remote Desktop.  All of that is working fine.  I was also able to create a new account and grant it access to Compute Engine resources.  That account can connect to the instance via SSH.  The specific problem I am having is connecting as the new user to the instance through Remote Desktop.

Comment: Here is a complete [official guide](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine) as well as troubleshooting steps, kindly add more details to your post.